# How to change culture info for RestSharp params

Tags: c#, windows-phone, globalization, restsharp

I have some variables of type `double` which I want to pass as GET parameters to my asp.net mvc client. However, e.g. `50.1` will be sent as `50,1` when using German language.

Whereas I can easily use `ToString` when adding the parameter with AddParameter method, it is not so easy when one relies on AddObject, like I do.

I use the following code:

```
var client = new RestClient(apiBaseUrl);

var request = new RestRequest(api);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddObject(data);

//...
```

Where can I change the `CultureInfo` that RestSharp uses?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like they're implicitly using current culture:

https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/RestRequest.cs#L286

Unless you want to patch their source, you could force the culture for the current thread using:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

And then just switch it back again after the call.

---

On another note, it looks like the `AddObject(...)` method uses non-compiled reflection, so it should be faster if you add the parameters for your objects using `AddParameter(...)` as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, looks like I have to do it that way... :( I thought that would be easier. I would really like to use AddParameter. But I use shared code in the ASP.NET MVC project and my WP8 app. That's where AddObject and automatic mapping of GET params to an object of the class make my life easier.

Comment: It would be trivial to copy their implementation and adjust it to fit your purposes. It doesn't look like their AddObject(...) references any request fields, it just calls AddParameter(...) internally.